Flying typewriters or sewing machines and the dangers of industrialisation
I'm desperately searching for an old cartoon I saw when I was a little child in the mid-90s. Unfortunately I don't remember all the details, rather the strange feeling it evoked in me. Here is a keyword like sketch of my memory/association with it:
Surrealistic black and white cartoon, utopian atmosphere, machines develop own's life, dark mood, flying typewriters or sewing machines, machine which spills a lot of oil, some kind of engines.
I remember that this "machines" started to fly and making a disturbing roaring sound. based on my biased (now adult) reconstruction I would say that the motif of this flick tried to capture a deep angst that came along with more and more industrialisation, but that could also be utterly wrong. (but looking at the images I get back when searching for "industrialization" capture this feeling pretty well) 
Without limiting the suggestions I would date it in a range of 1920-1940.
I searched several hours on YouTube and similar sites, no result. I know that my description is very vague but I don't have more info and I just hope that this keywords trigger some associations of movies/cartoon where one of them might be the one I search for.

Just in case someone else was actually following this, I found it! It's called The World of Machines:



You can see its actually way more recent (80's) then I estimated, but the style is quite unique with he collage-like scenes in between.
